# Place many different div elements to the right, each with height and width 100 percent (fullscreen)

Tags: html, css

im facing a problem where i need some advice.
I want to have a couple of main div containers lets say

```
<div class="main">
```

one to another to the right.

1. All main containers should have full width and height (fullscreen).
2. On the right I need a couple other main containers with the size and width of the former.

Is it possible to set the divs one another to the right without reading and setting it with javascript? Is there a css/html solution?

[image]

Example:

```
<div class="main"><!--to the right one more --> 
</div>

<div class="main"><!--to the right one more -->
</div>

<div class="main">
</div>
```

Style: #This doesn't work...

```
.main{
width:100%;
height:auto;
float: right;

}
```

Comment: Can you please re-provide your example code - I think you made a mistake while typing it up and nothing's showing in your questions

Comment: use style=display: inline for your divs

Comment: your question is soo confusing!!.. explaing better..

Comment: @Jurudocs Can you show us what you wanna do with image?

Comment: Are you asking for 3 containers lined up side by side, the total width filling the screen (i.e. each one is 33.3333%) and height of 100%?

Comment: @wheresrhys thank you so much for keeping with me! I added a mockup...hope that makes my question more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have misunderstood the question, but try

```
html, body {
   height: 100%;   
}

body {
    width: 300%;
}

.main {
   height: 100%;
   width: 33.333333333%;
   float: left;    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3yaJZ/

Comment: Hi Thanks for your try and your fiddle...I might get an idea how the thing i want is working... i set html, body to 300% and kept the .main css from you...i wanted those main divs not in width 33.33 but in 100 percent...

Comment: oh I see... have updated my answer accordingly to provide the desired effect

Answer (score 1):

hope what i've understood is what your trying to tell.. from my understanding,you want 3 div's ( main ) that will be in one bit component ( container ) each of which is 100% width and you can check each div as you scroll horizontally....

In your Css

```
body{
width:300%;
height:100%;
}
.main{
width:100%;
height:100%;
float:left;
}
```

And your html --

```
<body>
<div class="main"><!--to the right one more --> 
</div>

<div class="main"><!--to the right one more -->
</div>

<div class="main">
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks...the .main{with:100%} is not working but 33.33%  does

Comment: @jurudocs yup.. my bad.. `.main` takes the width relative to its parent i.e,the body -- since its already 300% - you should set it at 33.33% ( of 300 ) hence - u'll get the width to be ~100% of body..